# PHP SPL RegexIterator how files would be ordered?

Tags: php, iterator, spl

Let's say I have a snippet:

```
<?php
$directoryIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('some_dir_here');
$iteratorIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directoryIterator);
$regexp = '/hello_world[\d]*/';
$fileList = new RegexIterator($iteratorIterator, $regexp);
foreach ($fileList as $file) {
    echo $file . PHP_EOL;
}
```

It gets all files from `some_dir_here`, which match regexp.

How would be files in `$fileList` ordered (for example: by name ascending)? Are there any proofs in official docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) uses [`opendir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php), which doesn't sort its results.

If you want sorted results, you can use [`scandir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php), but it's not recursive or iterative.